# how to display the data entered in the form when reloading the page. In select2

Tags: php, jquery-select2

```
<select type="text" name="user_name" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%" >                                   
    <option></option>
    @foreach ($listUser as $items)            
    <option  value="{{$items->full_name}}">{{$items>full_name}}</option>                                 
    @endforeach   
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){       
        $('.select2').select2({
        placeholder : 'Chọn người dùng',
        allowClear: true,     
      });
    })
</script>
```

1. How to display the data entered in the form when reloading the page. In select2

Answer (score 1):

First You have to transform your data to the correct format in your controller, here you can see the correct data format:

```
var data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        full_name: 'John'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        full_name: 'Jane'
    }
];
```

You could pass the array in the correct format to the view, something like:

```
$users = \App\Models\User::all(); // eloquent collection

$users = $users->map(function ($user) {
    return ['id' => $user->id, 'full_name' => $user->full_name];
})->toArray();
```

It would give result in something like this:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "full_name" => "John"
  ]
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "full_name" => "Jane"
  ]
]
```

In you view you should prepare data for select2 as below:

```
<select type="text" name="user_name" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%" >         
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var users = {!! json_encode($users) !!};

    var data = $.map(users , function (value, key) {
        return {id: key, full_name: value};
    });

    $('.select2').select2({
        data: data

        placeholder : 'Chọn người dùng',
        allowClear: true,     
    });
</script>
```